# Mongoose concurrent save

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I' am trying to implement analytics in mongoose. Basically, each time a specific function is called (that my be very often), I search a document that gather all analytics (create it if it does not exists) and update it. In dev it works perfectly. However, because I wanted to mock analytics, I made thousands of calls like this:

```
FOR 0 to 500
  UPDATE_ANALYTICS[:
     LOAD_DOCUMENT
     UPDATE
     SAVE
  ]
END
```

But this doesn't work, only one update works. The reason is simple to understand, it loads the document 500 times, and then it saves it 500 times. But each time it update it, it only update what it loaded first, not the previously saved document. **How to solve that?**

The upload analytics schema (and function) looks like that:

```
Q = require "q"
schema = mongoose.Schema
  ref_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  evt_type: String # "dl" or "view"
  hits: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  total: Number

schema.methods =
  hit: (date=new Date()) ->
    # We create empty fields if necessary
    @hits = @hits or {}

    @hits[date.getFullYear()] = @hits[date.getFullYear()] or {}
    @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()] =
      @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()] or {}
    @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()] =
      @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()] or {}

    @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()][date.getHours()] =
      @hits[date.getFullYear()][date.getMonth()][date.getDate()][date.getHours()] + 1 or 1

    @total = @total + 1 or 1
    @markModified "hits"


schema.statics =
  hit: (type, refId, date=new Date()) ->
    deferred = Q.defer()
    Stat = mongoose.model "Stat"
    date = new Date date
    refId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId refId
    Stat.findOne(ref_id: refId, evt_type: type).exec().then (stat) ->
      if stat
        stat.hit date
        stat.save (err, doc) ->
          if err then return deferred.reject err
          deferred.resolve doc
        return
      stat = new Stat
        ref_id: refId
        evt_type: type
      stat.hit date
      stat.save (err, doc) ->
        if err then return deferred.reject err
        deferred.resolve doc
      return
    , console.log
    deferred.promise
mongoose.model "Stat", schema
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your actual node.js code?

Comment: Whatever code is calling the static `hit` method in a loop needs to wait until the returned promise is resolved before calling `hit` again.  Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, I understand but in a real life app there is no time to wait